# How do I know that a configuration is set up if I can't see it on my web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm walking through the Series on "**[How to use charts with ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx)**" (Scott Michell). Somewhere, he says:

*...Both of the above configuration additions are automatically added to Web.config when you add a Chart control to a web page for the first time in your project...*

I've checked on my web.config, but I didn't see anything. So, I manually added them. Now, when I try to run the program, I get the following error:

...The server tag '**asp:Chart**' is ambiguous. Please modify the associated registration that is causing ambiguity and pick a new tag prefix...

```
Line 4:  <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0,
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"...
```

It looks like things are working the way the author said. But, **How do I know that a configuration is set up if I can't see it on my web.config file?** Do I need to run first into an error?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023215

This explains that the page directive isn't needed any longer when moving to 4.0 version of the chart control dll.